# Manual PHP extension installation under Linux with Nginx

Tags: php, linux, nginx, debian

I need to add custom extension for PHP.

1. I copied the **extension_name.so** file to 'extension_dir' - /usr/lib/php/20190902
2. Created **extension_name.ini** file in /etc/php/7.4/mods-available
3. Created symlink **10-extension_name.ini** at /etc/php/7.4/fpm/conf.d (and in /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d)
4. Edited php.ini both for fpm and cli
5. Restarted fpm service
6. Checked that **/etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/10-extension_name.ini** present in *Additional .ini files parsed:* section in **php --ini** output

But when I run **php -m** extension_name.ini not in list. Also extension_name.ini not listed in phpinfo(); output. And when I run php code there is an error that Func_Name is Unknown.

Do I missed something?

PHP 7.4.6, Nginx 1.10.3, Debian 9

Comment: When you run php -m you are running CLI version, it uses another php.ini. Still, i wouldn't use another ini to do that, as default php come with  a "extension" section.

Comment: I edited both inis - for fpm and  for cli. Also I created .php file with phpinfo()